# I want to take into account double slashes (//) or more in url parameter value

Tags: url, url-parameters, slash

I would like that if my URL is domain/page?param=//, `$_GET[‘param’] == ‘//’`
Actualy, `$_GET[‘param’] == ‘/’`

To put some context, my URL domain/page is in fact rewritten in domain/index.php?action=page where the action parameter holds my route and parameters.

Lets’s say my action parameter value is ‘route/subroute/param1/param2’. Each part of the string is removed one after another starting by the end. If a route is find (ie route/subroute exists in my route array), then I call the controller etc… and the deduced parameters are param1 and param2.

Now I would like to take double or more following slashes into account for 2 reasons :

1. let’s say I have optional parameters a, b, c, and they are like this in URL : ‘a//c’. Then it is interpreted as ‘a/c’ and so b=’c’ instead of b=’’.
2. If I have route//subroute, I want it to be interpreted as an error (‘route//subroute’ doesn’t exists nor ‘route/’) and display an error view instead of it becoming valid (‘route/subroute’) to avoid duplicate content SEO wise.

Some sites manage to keep the URL intact and display an error view when typing domain//somepage or domain/somepage//subpage, so I guess it is possible.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using any rewrite rules?

Comment: Only for index.php?action=, so there's no rule that is affecting this.